# Notepad++ find string and append it to the end of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm looking for help with Notepad++ regex. I have a file with lines similar to this:

`(Donner, 1987) XviD, DVD/3, AC3 ITA - MP3 ENG, Subs, AVI`

I want to find the string `DVD/3` and move it to the end of its line. The string may vary, but I know how to find it.

How can I do this in Notepad++?

Comment: So would the correct output for the example line be: `(Donner, 1987) XviD, AC3 ITA - MP3 ENG, Subs, AVI DVD\3`?

Comment: According to this spec, the result should be `(Donner, 1987) XviD, , AC3 ITA - MP3 ENG, Subs, AVIDVD/3`. I agree that what (s)he wants is probably not what (s)he wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `, DVD/3` is the regex that finds your string, search for

```
(.*)(, DVD/3)(.*)
```

and replace it with

```
\1\3\2
```

Comment: @Ryan, the output (in this example) should be: (Donner, 1987) XviD, AC3 ITA - MP3 ENG, Subs, AVI, DVD\3

Comment: you are right, i didnt say that i need to "cut" ", DVD/3" and "paste" it at the end of the line.. i'm sorry i was'nt clear writing my question. Many thanks again :)